# Creating global registries using linker sections

Tags: c, linux, gcc, linker, inline-assembly

I have seen several projects using specific linker sections to create
registries of handlers (the following example are from the ahttpd integration
in eCos).

The idea is that it must be possible to hock in entries from different
compilations unites, into the same global registry.

The following is an simple example where I have tried to make this pattern
work, but something is clearly wrong as the programs exit code is 0, and I
expected it to be 3.

The code need not to be portable the only target is GCC under Linux.

Here is what I have tried:

```
#define HANDLER_TABLE_ENTRY(__var, __name, __val)          \
handler_table_entry __var                                  \
      __attribute__((section (".my.handler_table.data")))  \
      __attribute__((used)) = { __name, __val }

struct handler_table_entry {
    const char *name;
    int         val;
} __attribute__((aligned(8)));

// Beginning of section
__asm__(".section     \".my.handler_table.data\",\"aw\"\n"
        ".globl       handler_table\n"
        ".type        handler_table,object\n"
        ".p2align     3\n"
        "handler_table:\n"
        ".previous\n" );

// End of section
__asm__(".section     \".my.handler_table.data\",\"aw\"\n"
        ".globl       handler_table_end\n"
        ".type        handler_table_end,object\n"
        ".p2align     3\n"
        "handler_table_end:\n"
        ".previous\n" );

// Making the sections accessible from C
extern "C" handler_table_entry handler_table[];
extern "C" handler_table_entry handler_table_end[];

// Adding entries to the different sections. This may be done from different
// compilations unites
HANDLER_TABLE_ENTRY(entry_a, "entry_a", 10);
HANDLER_TABLE_ENTRY(entry_b, "entry_b", 20);
HANDLER_TABLE_ENTRY(entry_c, "entry_c", 30);

int main() {
    // Count the number of entries and return the value
    int cnt = 0;
    for (handler_table_entry *entry = handler_table;
            entry != handler_table_end; entry++)
        cnt ++;

    return cnt;  // returns 0, but I expected 3
}
```

Compiling:

```
g++ foo.cxx -o foo
```

Running and testing:

```
$ ./foo && echo $?
0
```

**Question 1:** What have I done wrong, and how would a simple working example
look like?

**Question 2:** Are there any pitfalls or scenarios where this pattern can not be
used? (ex. shared libraries)

### UPDATE:

I the process of trying to debug this problem I added the following line (and included stdio.h)

```
printf("0x%p 0x%p\n", (void *)handler_table, (void *)handler_table_end);
```

I changed my compilation command to:

```
gcc -static -O0 -g -o foo foo.c
```

When I run the program I get the following output:

```
$ ./foo
0x0x6b7650 0x0x6b7650
```

And here is what `objdump` has to say:

```
$ objdump -d --section=.my.handler_table.data foo

foo:     file format elf64-x86-64

Disassembly of section .my.handler_table.data:

00000000006b7650 <__TMC_END__>:
  6b7650:       64 a1 48 00 00 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00     d.H.............

00000000006b7660 <entry_2>:
  6b7660:       6c a1 48 00 00 00 00 00 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 00     l.H..... .......

00000000006b7670 <entry_3>:
  6b7670:       74 a1 48 00 00 00 00 00 30 00 00 00 00 00 00 00     t.H.....0.......
```

Clearly the problem is that `handler_table` and `handler_table_end` points to the same location, but why is this?

Comment: @Jens: Why do you not think assembly is the right tag? It is assembly facilities which makes this possible (or should make this possible). I think the reason why I can not figure out what is wrong is that I do not know assembly.

Comment: Didn't think it concerned assembly *language*. Perhaps the `inline-assembly` tag is appropriate.

Comment: You are right, I did not know the `inline-assembly` tag

Answer (score 0):

Chancing the name of the section where `handler_table_end` is placed solves the problem.

Here is what the complete code looks like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define HANDLER_TABLE_ENTRY(__var, __name, __val)          \
handler_table_entry __var                                  \
      __attribute__((section (".my.handler_table.data")))  \
      __attribute__((used)) = { __name, __val }

struct handler_table_entry {
    const char *name;
    int         val;
} __attribute__((aligned(8)));

// Beginning of section
__asm__(".section     \".my.handler_table.data\",\"aw\"\n"
        ".globl       handler_table\n"
        ".type        handler_table,object\n"
        ".p2align     3\n"
        "handler_table:\n"
        ".previous\n" );

// End of section. NOW IN A NEW SECTION
__asm__(".section     \".my.handler_table.data.end\",\"aw\"\n"
        ".globl       handler_table_end\n"
        ".type        handler_table_end,object\n"
        ".p2align     3\n"
        "handler_table_end:\n"
        ".previous\n" );

// Making the sections accessible from C
extern "C" handler_table_entry handler_table[];
extern "C" handler_table_entry handler_table_end[];

// Adding entries to the different sections. This may be done from different
// compilations unites
HANDLER_TABLE_ENTRY(entry_a, "entry_a", 10);
HANDLER_TABLE_ENTRY(entry_b, "entry_b", 20);
HANDLER_TABLE_ENTRY(entry_c, "entry_c", 30);

int main() {
    for (handler_table_entry *entry = handler_table;
            entry != handler_table_end; entry++)
        printf("%s -> %d\n", entry->name, entry->val);

    return 0;
}
```